# OAuth issue in Google AppEngine developing

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

i have encountered a weird problem in Google App Engine developing, every time is carry a body content in my post request, app engine failed to auth my account, but get request works.
can anybody help me? i'm using oauth library ChromeExOAuth in chrome extension developing.

```
    oauth.authorize(function(){
        var request = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {
                "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            'parameters': {
            },
            'body': "a=b"
        };
        oauth.sendSignedRequest("http://mytabshub.appspot.com/tabshub", function(resp, xhr){
            console.log("responding from test server", xhr.responseText);
        }, request);
    });
```

Comment: "get Request works" means were you able to exchange request_token for a access_token?

Comment: yeah! it exchanged. the library carry the access token in query string. but i guess app engine do not auth the account from query string in post request. so the auth process failed. it's so weird!

Comment: I have not developed app for Google app engine. But i am having same issue on integrating digg with my own oauth .net library. then i tested with twitter, it works fine. But this lack of documentation i havent sorted this out. Did you check with any other service like twitter? This helps to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For POST requests you must pass the oauth parameter url-encoded in the request body. The relavant code in the SDK is this (dev_appserver_oauth.py):

```
def _Parse(self, request, base_env_dict):
  """Parses a request into convenient pieces.

  Args:
    request: AppServerRequest.
    base_env_dict: Dictionary of CGI environment parameters.

  Returns:
    A tuple (method, path, headers, parameters) of the HTTP method, the
    path (minus query string), an instance of mimetools.Message with
    headers from the request, and a dictionary of parameter lists from the
    body or query string (in the form of {key :[value1, value2]}).
  """
  method = base_env_dict['REQUEST_METHOD']
  path, query = dev_appserver.SplitURL(request.relative_url)
  parameters = {}
  if method == 'POST':
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp=request.infile,
                            headers=request.headers,
                            environ=base_env_dict)
    for key in form:
      if key not in parameters:
        parameters[key] = []
      for value in form.getlist(key):
        parameters[key].append(value)
  elif method == 'GET':
    parameters = cgi.parse_qs(query)
  return method, path, request.headers, parameters
```

See that the query is only parsed in `GET` requests. For `POST`, it must be in the body.

Comment: may be i have found some clue, every time i send a post request with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content type, app engine reject me and complains auth failure. ...

Comment: Have you any reference on "must pass the oauth parameter url-encoded in the request body"? The RFC seems to only set a bit about order and preference.